# Add Tooltip to navbarMenu in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, shinybs

I would like to add a tooltip for navbarMenu in Shiny app. Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953873/add-tooltip-to-tabs-in-shiny) but, there is no answer.**Here is my reproducible code**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
       sidebarLayout( 
           sidebarPanel(),

           mainPanel(tabsetPanel(

             navbarMenu("Tab1",bsTooltip(id="Tab1", title="Short description  for the tab", trigger = "hover"), 
                 tabPanel("Tab1.1"),       
                 tabPanel("Tab1.2")),

            tabPanel("Tab2",tabsetPanel(
                       tabPanel("Tab2.1"),       
                       tabPanel("Tab2.2"))),

            tabPanel("Tab3",tabsetPanel(
                       tabPanel("Tab3.1"),
                       tabPanel("Tab3.2"),
                       tabPanel("Tab3.3")))
)))))
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

During my research I found this solution [R Shiny: Use navbarPage with bsModal by shinyBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530613/r-shiny-use-navbarpage-with-bsmodal-by-shinybs), but for `bsModel`.
Also, there is a procedure mentioned [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1q8&view/editor) which is based in java-script.I know both solutions are for tabpanel but I believe it's the same problem, which is navbarMenu and tabpanel don't have an id.
I'm statistician and I don't have background in HTML or java-script to rewrite the attribute for the tab title or navbarMenu.
I hope I phrase my question in a clear manner. Thanks in advance for your time and kind help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use HTML wenn passing the Title of the Tabs. in this case I just pt the title in a span and added the attribute `title`which is the attribute HTML uses default for mouse-overs. For me this is much sinpler the trying to add it over shinyBS.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel(),

    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(

      navbarMenu(span("Tab1",title="Short description  for the tab" ),
                 tabPanel("Tab1.1"),       
                 tabPanel("Tab1.2")),

      tabPanel("Tab2",tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Tab2.1"),       
        tabPanel("Tab2.2"))),

      tabPanel("Tab3",tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Tab3.1"),
        tabPanel("Tab3.2"),
        tabPanel("Tab3.3")))
    )))))
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. It's works also for tabpanel. Can you please also update the another question "Add Tooltip to Tab in Shiny", just for the future readers.

Comment: I have posted the same answer to the other qustion aswell

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution using javascript. Perhaps it may be more useful.
[image]

```r
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = navbarPage(
    tags$script(HTML('
           $( document ).on("shiny:sessioninitialized", function(event) {
                $(\'span[data-toggle="tooltip"]\').tooltip({
                    html: true
                });      
           });'
    )),
    navbarMenu(
      "Menu"
      ,tabPanel(span("navbarTitle 1",title="XXX",`data-toggle`="tooltip"),
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel(span("Tab 1", title = "aaa",`data-toggle`="tooltip")),
          tabPanel(span("Tab 2",title="bbb",`data-toggle`="tooltip")),
          tabPanel(span("Tab 3",title="ccc",`data-toggle`="tooltip"))
        )    
      )
      ,tabPanel( "navbarTitle 2")
      
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
  }
)
```